# Why is my JSlider not changing the value?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, jslider

I am trying to make my program so that an integer value entered in a JTextfield can be stored into a variable. Then, when a JButton is clicked, this variable can tell a JSlider to move it's head to that of the integer value stored in the variable. My class name is Camera.Java
Code is showing no errors, however if I click my JButton, nothing happens, instead I see this error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at Camera.main(Camera.java:67)
```

My code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;

  public class Camera {

  static JButton addtolist;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static JSlider cam = new JSlider();
    static JTextField enterval = new JTextField();
    static int x ;

public static void main (String args[]){
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame ("Matthew Damon on Mars");
    myFrame.setSize(300, 600);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    JLabel userinp = new JLabel("Enter input: ");

    cam = new JSlider(0, 15, 0);
    cam.setPaintLabels(true);

    enterval.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,80));

    addtolist = new JButton("Enter");
    addtolist.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
    JTextField enterval1 = new JTextField();

    panel.add(addtolist);

    Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> table = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
    table.put(0, new JLabel("0"));
    table.put(1, new JLabel("1"));
    table.put(2, new JLabel("2"));
    table.put(3, new JLabel("3"));
    table.put(4, new JLabel("4"));
    table.put(5, new JLabel("5"));
    table.put(6, new JLabel("6"));
    table.put(7, new JLabel("7"));
    table.put(8, new JLabel("8"));
    table.put(9, new JLabel("9"));
    table.put(10, new JLabel("A"));
    table.put(11, new JLabel("B"));
    table.put(12, new JLabel("C"));
    table.put(13, new JLabel("D"));
    table.put(14, new JLabel("E"));
    table.put(15, new JLabel("F"));
    cam.setLabelTable(table);

    myFrame.add(cam, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    myFrame.add(userinp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    myFrame.add(enterval1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    myFrame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    buttonAction();

}





public static void buttonAction() {

addtolist.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

          try {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(enterval.getText());
              cam.setValue(x);
          } catch (NumberFormatException npe) {
              // show a warning message
          }
    }

});
}       

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your setting `x` on program creation before the user has had any chance to change its value. Get the text value from within the `actionPerformed` method which should be after the user has already selected a value, parse it into a number and set the slider with that value.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(enterval.getText());
            cam.setValue(x);
        } catch (NumberFormatException npe) {
            // show a warning message
        }
    }
```

Then get rid of all that static nonsense. The only method that should be static here is main, and it should do nothing but create an instance and set it visible.

Note that better than using a `JTextField`, use a `JSpinner` or a `JFormattedTextField` or if you're really stuck, a `DocumentFilter` to limit what the user can enter

Comment: Oh, I can I upvote again for the *"static nonsense*"!!

Comment: @MadProgrammer: you can vote for any and all you want. :) a wiki answer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I forgot to mention your favorite tool for this sort of thing: JSpinner. I've fixed this.

Comment: The code above still doesn't work, it returns this error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at Camera.main(Camera.java:65)

Comment: @VirenSareen: have you gotten rid of the offending code where you're parsing the text on program creation? Edit your question and show your latest code.

Comment: I only changed the little class at the bottom: public static void buttonAction() {
    addtolist.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           try {
              int x = Integer.parseInt(enterval.getText());
                  cam.setValue(x);
              } catch (NumberFormatException npe) {
                  // show a warning message
              }
        }

    });
}       

 }

Comment: @VirenSareen: don't show code in comments. Again, edit your question and show your changes. Again, do you get rid of the offending line of code that several of us have mentioned?

Comment: Code updated. If you're referring to 'static' statements as offending line of code, I can't get rid of that, I'm using Eclipse and it automatically adds it on for me, without it, the program doesn't run

Comment: That's because you're fixing the it the wrong way. The solution is not to make everything static, but rather to create instances and call your methods in non static ways.

Comment: How would I exactly go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Again, you should put most everything into the instance realm and out of the static realm. This means getting most of that code outside of the main method and into other methods and constructors, that means not trying to access fields or methods from the class, but rather from the instance. For instance, your main method should only create the main instances, hook them up and set them running and that's it. It should not be used to build the specific GUI components. For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CameraFoo extends JPanel {
    // only static field here is a constant.
    private static String TEXTS = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    private JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    private JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 15, 0);

    public CameraFoo() {    
        List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>();
        Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> table = new Hashtable<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < TEXTS.toCharArray().length; i++) {
            char c = TEXTS.charAt(i);
            String myText = String.valueOf(c);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(myText);
            table.put(i, label);
            charList.add(c);
        }
        SpinnerListModel spinnerModel = new SpinnerListModel(charList);
        spinner.setModel(spinnerModel);
        slider.setLabelTable(table);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(spinner);
        topPanel.add(new JButton(new ButtonAction("Press Me")));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(slider);
    }

    private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ButtonAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            char ch = (char) spinner.getValue();
            int value = TEXTS.indexOf(ch);
            slider.setValue(value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        CameraFoo mainPanel = new CameraFoo();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CameraFoo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```